# Zend File Validator multiple file error

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework

`Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http` validator acts very strange and I just can't make it work properly. Here's the code

```
const MAX_FILES = 3;
const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 2097152; # 2MB
const ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = 'jpg,jpeg,png,gif,pdf,mp4,avi,3gp';

public $mimes = [
    'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
    'gif' =>'image/gif',
    'jpeg' =>'image/jpeg',
    'jpg' =>'image/jpeg',
    'png' =>'image/png',
    'mp4' =>'video/mp4',
    'mp4-2' =>'application/mp4',
    'avi' =>'video/x-msvideo',
    '3gp' =>'video/3gpp'
];

...

$this->upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http(['ignoreNoFile' => false]);
$this->upload ->addValidator('Count', false, self::MAX_FILES)
        ->addValidator('Size', false, self::MAX_FILE_SIZE)
        ->addValidator('Extension', false, self::ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS) #array_keys($mimes);
        ->addValidator('MimeType', false, array_values($this->mimes))
        ->setDestination($this->dir);

# Checks the files
for($x = 1; $x <= self::MAX_FILES; $x++) {
    var_dump($this->upload->isValid('file' . $x));
    var_dump($this->upload->getFileName('file' . $x));
    if( !$this->upload->isValid('file' . $x) && !empty( $this->upload->getFileName('file' . $x) ) ) {
        $messages[] = 'file';
    }
}
```

My issue:
When I upload *file1* and *file2* as an `.jpg` image, whereas *file3* is not entered, it successfully validates those 2 files and skips the 3rd one. However when I upload the same files as *file1* and *file3*, validator says *file3* is not valid (but still skips empty *file2* input).

I originally had `ignoreNoFile` set on true, but then it only validated first file and *file2 & file3* could've been `.php` files and yet they passed through the validator.

How would you make validator work as desired?

`if file input is empty -> skip`, 
`if not -> validate` (but correctly).

EDIT: Here's how I generate inputs in view script based on `max_files` const in the controller.

```
 <input type="submit" value="<?= $this->translate('SEND')?>" class="submit submit_final" name="submit"/>
<? if(in_array('file', $this->messages)){ echo '<span class="form-error">'.$this->translate('CONTACT_FORM_FILE_NOT_VALID').'</span>';} ?>
<?php for($x = 1; $x < $this->max_files+1; $x++) { ?>
    <input name="file<?= $x ?>" type="file" class="input" />
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by simply preventing user to upload files in random order by javascript.